# Does $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} y\sin(1/x)$ exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} y\sin(1/x)$$
with the change of variable $y = \frac 1u$, $x = \frac 1v$, $u, v \to \infty$, we get
$$\lim_{(u,v) \to (\infty, \infty)} \frac{\sin v}{u}$$
which tends to $0$, hence the limit is $0$.

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717811/does-lim-x-y-to0-0x-sin-1-yy-sin-1-x-exist) question, which states that a similar limit exists. However, my textbook (Thomas Finney) mentions that the **limit does not exist**

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: The limit should exist because $-y<y\sin(1/x)<y$ and Sandwich Lemma

Comment: Can you say in exactly which page does he claim that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe the book is referring to

$$\lim_{(u,v) \to (0, 0)} \frac{\sin v}{u}$$

or to a different limit?

Comment: @UserA this is problem 13 on page 805 (2nd exercise, Chp. 15), and the answers are written in the back (Pg A-83)

Comment: @user no, this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a copy of Thomas & Finney to know how it defines limits for functions of two (or more) variables, but some textbooks require that the function be defined at *all* points in some ball around $(a,b)$, except possibly for $(a,b)$ itself, in order for the limit as $(x,y)\to(a,b)$ to exist. The expression $y\sin(1/x)$ is not defined along the $y$ axis ($x=0$), so in that sense the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ does not exist. I would suggest looking carefully at your book's definitions.

Comment: You may be right. The book defines limit of $f(x,y)$ at $(x_0,y_0)$  as the number $L$ for which $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$,$0<|y-y_0|<\delta$ and $|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb, the non-existence of a limit on a domain-related technicality is subtle enough I would expect there to be some discussion of it in the text itself. Are you sure the exercise you cited in comments is the only place where the issue seems to arise?

Comment: positive. Other examples cite difference in limits on taking different approach paths eg $y=mx$ and $y=kx^2$ give different results, but nothing of this sort. I'm accepting this answer for now, but I'll change if a better one comes up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, indeed we have that since $|\sin v| \le 1$

$$\left|\frac{\sin v}{u}\right| \le \left|\frac 1u\right|\to 0$$

and therefore by squeeze theorem the limit exists equal to zero.